# UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService'

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, docker-compose, spring-data

I'm working on a Spring Boot project using MongoDB as the database. I'm not sure why this error is constantly occurring every time I try to run this `noDuplicateEmail` test.

**Error Messages**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'contactService' defined in file [/Users/gs97ahn/Development/spring-workspace/gabojait-spring/out/production/classes/com/inuappcenter/gabojaitspring/user/service/ContactService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactRepository' defined in com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.repository.ContactRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongodbConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/inuappcenter/gabojaitspring/config/MongodbConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [com/inuappcenter/gabojaitspring/config/MongodbConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain '/'
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'contactRepository' defined in com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.repository.ContactRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongodbConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mongoTemplate' while setting bean property 'mongoOperations'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/inuappcenter/gabojaitspring/config/MongodbConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mongoTemplate' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoDbFactory' defined in class path resource [com/inuappcenter/gabojaitspring/config/MongodbConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory]: Factory method 'mongoDbFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain '/'
```

**Test**

```java
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.domain.Contact;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.dto.ContactDefaultResponseDto;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.dto.ContactSaveRequestDto;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.service.ContactService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionException;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@SpringBootTest
public class ContactServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    ContactService contactService;

    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void noDuplicateEmail() {
        // given
        ContactSaveRequestDto request = new ContactSaveRequestDto();
        request.setEmail("email@domain.com");

        // when
        ContactDefaultResponseDto response = contactService.saveTest(request);

        // then
        Contact foundContact = contactService.findByEmail(response.getEmail());
        assertThat(response.getEmail()).isEqualTo(foundContact.getEmail());
    }
}
```

**Domain**

```java
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Getter
@Document(collection = "contact")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Contact {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotBlank
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotBlank
    private String verificationCode;

    @NotBlank
    private Boolean isVerified;

    @NotBlank
    private Boolean isRegistered;

    @NotBlank
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @NotBlank
    private LocalDateTime modifiedDate;

    @NotBlank
    private String schemaVersion;

    @Builder(builderClassName = "ByContactBuilder", builderMethodName = "ByContactBuilder")
    public Contact(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setVerificationCode(String verificationCode) {
        this.verificationCode = verificationCode;
    }

    public void setIsVerified(Boolean isVerified) {
        this.isVerified = isVerified;
    }

    public void setIsRegistered(Boolean isRegistered) {
        this.isRegistered = isRegistered;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate) {
        this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(LocalDateTime modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setSchemaVersion(String schemaVersion) {
        this.schemaVersion = schemaVersion;
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```java
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.domain.Contact;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface ContactRepository extends MongoRepository<Contact, String> {
    public Optional<Contact> findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Service**

```java
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.domain.Contact;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.dto.ContactDefaultResponseDto;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.dto.ContactSaveRequestDto;
import com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring.user.repository.ContactRepository;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Random;

@Service
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class ContactService {

    private final ContactRepository contactRepository;

    @Transactional
    public ContactDefaultResponseDto saveTest(ContactSaveRequestDto request) {
        Contact savedContact = contactRepository.save(request.toEntity());
        savedContact.setVerificationCode(generateVerificationCode());
        return new ContactDefaultResponseDto(savedContact);
    }

    private String generateVerificationCode() {
        String chars = "0123456789" + "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" + "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Random random = new Random();
        random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            sb.append(chars.charAt(random.nextInt(chars.length())));
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public Contact findByEmail(String email) {
        try {
            Optional<Contact> contact = contactRepository.findByEmail(email);
            if (contact.isEmpty()) {
                log.error("");
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            } else {
                return contact.get();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("", e);
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
    }
}
```

**MongoDbConfiguration**

```java
import com.mongodb.ConnectionString;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDatabaseFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoClientConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring")
public class MongodbConfiguration extends AbstractMongoClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MongoTransactionManager transactionManager(MongoDatabaseFactory dbFactory) {
        return new MongoTransactionManager(dbFactory);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "gabojait";
    }

    @Override
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        final ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString("mongodb://localhost:27017/gabojait/?retryWrites=false");
        final MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        return MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
        return Collections.singleton("com.inuappcenter.gabojaitspring");
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=admin
spring.data.mongodb.username=root
spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
spring.data.mongodb.database=gabojait
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

### Cause

What the error says:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: state should be: databaseName does not contain '/'
```

is that your connection string is not valid.

### Solve

Remove slash after database name.

Change the connection string:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/gabojait/?retryWrites=false
```

to:

```
mongodb://localhost:27017/gabojait?retryWrites=false
```

### Why this happens

Database name should not contain slash character.

> A valid database name is non-null, non-empty, and does not contain any of the following characters: {@code '\0', '/', '\', ' ', '"', '.'}. The server may impose additional restrictions on database names.
> [See more](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/61ac1d44df29e077bf17c7c866f109a5c12c0814/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/MongoNamespace.java#L51-L68)

When you pass the connection string to the MongoDB driver, it [splits down the string into multiple parts](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/61ac1d44df29e077bf17c7c866f109a5c12c0814/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.java#L370-L394):

- host: `localhost`
- port: `27017`
- database: `gabojait/`
- options:

  - `retryWrites=false`

The driver does not remove the unexpected trailing comma. So you got the wrong database name, seeing `IllegalArgumentException` thrown by the [validator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/61ac1d44df29e077bf17c7c866f109a5c12c0814/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/MongoNamespace.java#L65).

Correct format of the connection string is:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database.collection][?options]]
```

Or simply for single host:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host[/[database][?options]]
```